# Select from table where value in common with another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables ( `visited` and `purchased` )

```
visited -> id,product,user_ip
purchased -> id,product,user_ip
```

which eventually have the the same value in the column `user_ip`. Example:

```
visited ->
1,product1,192.168.1.1
2,product2,192.168.1.1
3,product3,192.168.12.12
4,product4,192.168.12.12

purchased ->
1,product3,192.168.12.12
```

Is possible to select all `products` from `visited` which have `user_ip` in common with `purchased`? In the above example I would need to select `id3` and `id4`.

Comment: "Yes, it is" would be a formally correct answer to your question... (Until you answer Naveed's question.)

Comment: Sorry, i've tried **Vadiklk** and **Lukas Eder** and both offer same OK results, still prefer Vadiklk option. Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM visited
WHERE user_ip IN (SELECT user_ip FROM purchased)
```

This may be slow if you don't have the correct indexes set up on the `user_ip` columns...

Answer (score 2):

Try this, post a comment if you need me to edit.

```
SELECT *
FROM visited
INNER JOIN purchased
ON visited.user_ip=purchased.user_ip
ORDER BY visited.id
```

You could change the select to only what you need btw (if you only need id).